Prefect 3 - Error running task with a custom Docker container
I have a project with a simple python file that is containerized with a Dockerfile.
The dockerfile is:
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "prefect-test.py"]

prefect-test.py
is a simple file that print a message. If I build the image locally with Docker Desktop and run it, it works. I already pushed it on docker hub in a public repo.
Now I want to start a Prefect server versione 3 (not 2, it's important).
I created this Dokefile:
FROM prefecthq/prefect:3-latest

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["prefect", "server", "start", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]

I build the image and ran it with:
docker build -t prefect-server .

docker run -d -p 4200:4200 --name prefect-server prefect-server

Then I access the GIU with:
http://localhost:4200
Everything works.
Now I want to create a work pool, start an agent and do a deploy. The target is to create a deploy file that run the Dockerimage that run the prefect-test.py file.
I create the work pool with:
prefect work-pool create --type docker my-work-pool

I started a worker:
prefect worker start --pool docker my-work-pool

Now I have to define the deployment. I created a file named deploy_buy.py in a different folder than the root where I have the Dockerfile and prefect-test.py file:
from prefect import flow

@flow(log_prints=True)
def buy():
    print("Selling securities")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    buy.deploy(
        name="my-deployment",
        work_pool_name="my-work-pool",
        image="docker.io/xxx/image"
    )

I copied it from official doc here: https://docs.prefect.io/v3/deploy/infrastructure-examples/docker
If I run the task, I see the message "Buying securities" in logs and at the end I see:
Finished in state Completed()
Process for flow run 'xxx' exited cleanly.
But the file prefect-test.py wasn't invoked, because I don't see any other log.
I used a different folder for deploy file because, if I don't do that, when I run deploy, it gives me an error saying that a Dockerfile is already in that folder. Executing in a different folder, it creates automatically a Dockerfile with this:
FROM prefecthq/prefect:3.1.4-python3.10
COPY . /opt/prefect/deploy/
WORKDIR /opt/prefect/deploy/
This is not clear, because that file doesn't contain anything about how to run my prefect-test.py file. For this reason I created another deploy file in the root of my project with this:
from prefect import flow
from prefect.docker import DockerImage

@flow(log_prints=True)
def buy():
    print("Selling securities")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    buy.deploy(
        name="my-deployment",
        work_pool_name="my-work-pool",
        image=DockerImage(
            name="docker.io/xxx/image",
            dockerfile="Dockerfile"
        ), 
        push=False
    )

I used dockerfile="Dockerfile" because I want Prefect to use my Dockerfile. If I remove that line and try to make a deploy, as I wrote above, Prefect tells me that I already have a Dockerfile in that folder. With that line, I get no error.
I don't want prefect create another build and push it, but I want it uses the image I already have on dockerhub. For this reason I put also:
push=False

If I deploy it and run the task, I get error:
    timestamp,level,flow_run_id,task_run_id,message
2024-12-01 15:06:40.326981+00:00,20,b89520d8-a1ca-4802-b2f0-c998e81c6029,,Worker 'DockerWorker e7ea2375-4f9b-4a61-a31e-a81e2b9c3ce0' submitting flow run 'b89520d8-a1ca-4802-b2f0-c998e81c6029'
2024-12-01 15:06:41.402569+00:00,20,b89520d8-a1ca-4802-b2f0-c998e81c6029,,Completed submission of flow run 'b89520d8-a1ca-4802-b2f0-c998e81c6029'
2024-12-01 15:06:44.210221+00:00,20,b89520d8-a1ca-4802-b2f0-c998e81c6029,,Opening process...
2024-12-01 15:06:46.943062+00:00,20,b89520d8-a1ca-4802-b2f0-c998e81c6029,,Downloading flow code from storage at '.'
2024-12-01 15:06:47.181580+00:00,40,b89520d8-a1ca-4802-b2f0-c998e81c6029,,"Flow could not be retrieved from deployment.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ""<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>"", line 850, in exec_module
File ""<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File ""deploy.py"", line 2, in <module>
from prefect.docker import DockerImage
ImportError: cannot import name 'DockerImage' from 'prefect.utilities.dockerutils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/utilities/dockerutils.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/engine.py"", line 414, in retrieve_flow_then_begin_flow_run
flow = await load_flow_from_flow_run(flow_run, client=client)
File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/client/utilities.py"", line 51, in with_injected_client
return await fn(*args, **kwargs)
File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/deployments/deployments.py"", line 264, in load_flow_from_flow_run
flow = await run_sync_in_worker_thread(load_flow_from_entrypoint, str(import_path))
File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/utilities/asyncutils.py"", line 91, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py"", line 33, in run_sync
return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py"", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
return await future
File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py"", line 807, in run
result = context.run(func, *args)
File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/flows.py"", line 1539, in load_flow_from_entrypoint
flow = import_object(entrypoint)
File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/utilities/importtools.py"", line 201, in import_object
module = load_script_as_module(script_path)
File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/utilities/importtools.py"", line 164, in load_script_as_module
raise ScriptError(user_exc=exc, path=path) from exc
prefect.exceptions.ScriptError: Script at 'deploy.py' encountered an exception: ImportError(""cannot import name 'DockerImage' from 'prefect.utilities.dockerutils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/utilities/dockerutils.py)"")"
2024-12-01 15:06:47.600011+00:00,20,b89520d8-a1ca-4802-b2f0-c998e81c6029,,Process for flow run 'nimble-wildcat' exited cleanly.

This is strange because that import is the same of the one in the example on Prefect v3 docs.
Any ideas?
Thanks

I work on the open source at prefect, sorry you're having trouble and thanks for the reproduction steps!
are you able to share the full stack trace? its odd to me that from prefect.docker import DockerImage would raise that error
also, please feel free to copy this writeup into a GitHub discussion (https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/discussions), which is the best place to ask these sorts of questions
otherwise, feel free to join our slack if you want to chat with us or ask other prefect users questions
https://communityinviter.com/apps/prefect-community/prefect-community

Hi Stoat and thanks for your reply
I already posted the same on slack channel. Now I will post also on GitHub discussions.
Can you tell me how to share the full stack trace please?
I cut only error parts, but I can add all I see on log. I will edit the last part of my original post in a minute with all I see there. Thanks
